# Connect to VPN always ask password

Tags: ios, swift, vpn, keychain

I am trying to connect VPN using NETWORK EXTENSION framework, but it's always ask me to enter password. I don't know why because it looks like everything successfully getting from Keychain, maybe I'm wrong. Here is my code:

```
func createVPN() {
        let manager: NEVPNManager = NEVPNManager.sharedManager()
        let keychain = KeychainSwift()

        manager.loadFromPreferencesWithCompletionHandler { (error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                print("error")
            } else {
                let p = NEVPNProtocolIKEv2()
                p.remoteIdentifier = "*******"
                p.username = "*******"
                p.passwordReference = keychain.getData("vpnpassword")!
                p.serverAddress = "free-nl.hide.me"
                p.authenticationMethod = NEVPNIKEAuthenticationMethod.None
                p.useExtendedAuthentication = true
                p.disconnectOnSleep = false
                manager.`protocol` = p
                manager.enabled = true
                manager.saveToPreferencesWithCompletionHandler({ (error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    if (error != nil) {
                        print(error)
                    } else {
                        do {
                            try NEVPNManager.sharedManager().connection.startVPNTunnel()
                        } catch {
                            print("can't connect VPN'")
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

P.S. When I enter password by myself it works fine.

And also I can't understand why createVPN function works only if it's called from viewDidLoad, this way not:

```
@IBAction func initVPN(sender: AnyObject) {
   self.createVPN()
}
```

**SOLUTION:**

The problem was in Keychain

Solution was to use objc functions for saving and getting data:

```
+ (void) storeData: (NSString * )key data:(NSData *)data {
    NSLog(@"Store Data");
    NSMutableDictionary * dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dict setObject:(__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword forKey:(__bridge id)kSecClass];
    NSData *encodedKey = [key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [dict setObject:encodedKey forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrGeneric];
    [dict setObject:encodedKey forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount];
    [dict setObject:@"VPN" forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrService];
    [dict setObject:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessibleAlwaysThisDeviceOnly forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessible];
    [dict setObject:data forKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];

    OSStatus status = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)dict, NULL);
    if(errSecSuccess != status) {
        NSLog(@"Unable add item with key =%@ error:%d",key,(int)status);
    }
}

+ (NSData *) getData: (NSString *)key {
    NSMutableDictionary * dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dict setObject:(__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword forKey:(__bridge id)kSecClass];
    NSData *encodedKey = [key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [dict setObject:encodedKey forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrGeneric];
    [dict setObject:encodedKey forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount];
    [dict setObject:@"VPN" forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrService];
    [dict setObject:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessibleAlwaysThisDeviceOnly forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessible];
    [dict setObject:(__bridge id)kSecMatchLimitOne forKey:(__bridge id)kSecMatchLimit];
    [dict setObject:(id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:(__bridge id)kSecReturnPersistentRef];

    CFTypeRef result = NULL;
    OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)dict,&result);

    if( status != errSecSuccess) {
        NSLog(@"Unable to fetch item for key %@ with error:%d",key,(int)status);
        return nil;
    }

    NSData *resultData = (__bridge NSData *)result;
    return resultData;
}
```

Comment: If you found a solution, please post it as an answer instead of editing your question (posting an answer to your own question is absolutely ok). Thank you. :)

Comment: Ok. I'm newbie here. Thanks:)

Comment: My understanding is that VPN will ALWAYS ask password unless it's a certificate-based connection (which is a bummer)

Comment: Guys any updates ? for password based connection will it ask every time ? and in certificate based approach will not ask ?